# ASP.NET Core UserManager Find not Include Roles And RemoveFromRole Fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to remove user from role but it's always failed.

I see `userManager.FindByIdasync()` return's user not include Roles.
But I cant use `userManager.GetRolesAsync()` to get all roles information.

[Image: Visual Studio Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxTDC.png)

I cheange the identityRole's PK from string to Guid and rename to applicationRole, is that the reason for that?

> ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    private ApplicationRole()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
    {
    }
}
```

> Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

> ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid> { 
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customizations
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(i =>
        {
            i.ToTable("Users");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(i =>
        {
            i.ToTable("Roles");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
    }
}
```

Why are the roles for this user not being included in result?

And When I try to call `userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync()` to remove user form role, nothing will happens. No any SQL query send to database and no any exception happens.

Is it because the user does not have a role? or it's other problem?